# Hide a element inside wrapper using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to close 'multiselectPopUp' unorderlist element when clicked target is outside "multiselectWrapper" div element.

```
 <div class="multiselectWrapper">
    <input type="text" class="multiselectTextBox"/>
    <ul class="multiselectPopUp">
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
    </ul>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $('.multiselectPopUp').hide();
        $(document).click(function (e) {
            debugger;
            if ($(e.target).is('.multiselectTextBox')) {
                $('.multiselectPopUp').show();
            }
            else if(// Plese provide me selector logic here){                   
                $('.multiselectPopUp').hide();
            }
        });
    });

 });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 <div class="multiselectWrapper">
         <input type="text" class="multiselectTextBox"/>
         <ul class="multiselectPopUp">
           <li>One</li>
           <li>Two</li>
        </ul>
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">

  $(function () {

    $('.multiselectPopUp').hide();
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        debugger;
        if ($(e.target).is('.multiselectTextBox')) {
            $('.multiselectPopUp').show();
        }
        else if ($(e.target).is('.multiselectPopUp') || $(e.target).is('.multiselectPopUp > li')) { 
            $('.multiselectPopUp').show();
       }
       else {
           $('.multiselectPopUp').hide();
       }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.multiselectPopUp').hide();
        $(document).click(function (e) {
            if ($(e.target).is('.multiselectTextBox')) {
                $('.multiselectPopUp').show();
            }
            else if($(e.target).closest('.multiselectWrapper').length === 0){                   
                $('.multiselectPopUp').hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FPbWu/1/)**

Comment: list should not close when i click inside "div.multiselectWrapper" anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.closest()` in this context to identify whether the target is the descendant of `.multiselectWrapper` or not.

Try,

```
if ($(e.target).is('.multiselectTextBox')) {
     $('.multiselectPopUp').show();
}
else if($(e.target).closest('.multiselectWrapper').length === 0){                   
     $('.multiselectPopUp').hide();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Jquery

```
$('ul.class').hide();
```

or

```
$('ul.class').css('display','none');
```